# Automatically start machine if another fails

Tags: backup, hp, ping

Is it possible to get a backup server (machine) to automatically start if the main server (machine) fails (i.e. does not longer respond to ping, or something).

We're talking physical servers, not virtualized, and in different datacenters. We've got HP servers with ILO on them, if it matters.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe? You'd need to provide a LOT more information like server model, OS, application... perhaps a failure scenario, because most quality servers don't just "fail".

Comment: Plus do they have to be off or can it be running but not active (i.e standby). In which case you can look at things like heartbeat if it's linux.